# How to add online login to android app

Tags: java, android, authentication, upload, share

I have an android app that needs online login and online sharing pictures on different categories.
but i don't know anything about servers , online databases and etc , where can i start ?
(PHP,MYSQL,SQLite for server initializing and server itself)

for now i just created offline app body which is not a big deal.

Comment: This question is too broad and is unlikely to receive high quality fact-based answers.  Can you refine your question to something with which people can provide specific programming help; a search engine is your best place to find tutorials on creating web servers

Comment: exactly but one of em uses sql server , one other uses mysql and ... , i'm really confused about it

Comment: Do you want to know how to implement the log in module for your app or do you want to know how to implement the log in architecture for your 'entire environment' i.e app, webservices, database etc

Comment: entire environment, android app ios app and website itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting the learn the same concepts as well. I've heard OAuth is the place to start. Using these resources currently:

[Android OAuth Client](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/315)

[Google Login](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1127)

[Facebook Login](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/899)

Otherwise I agree with the previous comments, mySQL with PHP script for login / encryption (which would require a server). Maybe find a way to do it with [Parse](https://www.parse.com/?) backend and encryption?

Best of luck!